# treetagger module returns empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, part-of-speech, treetagger

I made a sentiment analysis program with treetagger. It worked fine two weeks ago but now it doesn't works properly.

After that I used treetagger in a very simple program which returns "hello world"'s tagging. It doesn't work properly again. I coded like this :

```
from treetagger import TreeTagger

tt = TreeTagger(path_to_treetagger = "./treetagger/") # treetagger file is in the same directory

tt.tag("hello world")
```

It returns this =>  [['']]

I fulfilled the direcions from "http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/" to install treetagger. And I am using treetagger.py as a module from https://github.com/miotto/treetagger-python . All of the files are in the same directory .

I am using Python 3.6.7 and GCC version is 7.3.0. My OS is Kali Linux with dual boot Windows 10 on a Laptop.

I formatted and reinstalled Kali to my laptop because of corruption in pip. So treetagger was working before this operation. I think that is the case but I am not sure.

The question is briefly: "How to use treetagger properly?" 
What do you think?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Isn't there anyone to answer it? I can't find enough documentation of this module.

Comment: Lol, TreeTagger is an odd-ball tool that has its source code lost in the internet. But the documentation on the Helmut Schmid's site. It has little to do with `nltk` though, so going to remove the tag.

Comment: You'll get more help with the `nlp` tag =)